# How to print value differences between 2 dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

So I have these 2 dictionaries (note the difference in the first key):

```
dict1= {'an': 2,
        'at': 4,
        'ao': 2,
        'ct': 6}

dict2= {'an': 1,
        'at': 4,
        'ao': 2,
        'ct': 6}
```

I want to compare the values to print the values in dict2 that are different from those found in dict1.  I also want to print the key in dict2 that has the mismatching value.  I've tried this but it just prints out all the keys and values of dict2:

```
for k,v in dict2.items():
    if dict2[k] != dict1[k]:
        print(k, dict2[k])
```

Can someone help me understand why this isn't working?

Comment: It's working as intended... I get `an 1` printed out... Tested on 3.5.2 linux box....

Comment: No repro. On, Win7, python 3.5.2, works as well.

Comment: Are you 100% sure thats exactly what you used?

Comment: Would it have to do with the way my dictionary is being created?  dict1 I created manually and dict2 was created with:

counts = dict()
for i in lst:
    counts[i] = counts.get(i, 0) + 1

where lst is the list I created the dictionary from and count is the name of the dictionary

Comment: Maybe check that your indentation matches the indentation of the code sample that you posted.

Comment: This should most definitely give you the result you want, although there is no need to get `dict2[k]` for the value - in this case you already have it stored in `v`.

Comment: @e9e9s what are your actual dictionaries?

Comment: `1 != '1'`. Perhaps it is a type issue. Maybe `dict1` has string values and `dict2` has int values. As it is, no one can reproduce to your problem, so we can do nothing but guess.

Comment: This method you are testing with relies on the keys being the same for each dictionary, as in both dictionary should have the same number of keys and the same set of keys. Make sure that's true.

Comment: Ok so here what I found out: When I manually (i.e. type it out) create dict2 with a value mismatch then the code works.  But when I programatically create dict2  (e.g. counts = dict() for i in lst: counts[i] = counts.get(i, 0) + 1) then it prints out ALL the key value pairs for dict2.  I just don't understand this behavior.